# How can we pass dynamic variable from any component.ts to style.less in angular 6?

Tags: angular6, less, mean-stack

I have one component named as `header.ts` which is in component directory and my `style.less` file is out of that component directory, I want to know how could I pass my dynamic variable from component `header.ts` to `style.less`

```
header.component.ts 
this.backgroundColor = 'red'
```

I want to pass `this.backgroundColor` to class `.testCss` of `style.less`  like below code,

```
.testCss{
 background: this.backgroundColor;
}
```